# Deadlock on xUnit Test when Processing Data on Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, database-connection, integration-testing, xunit

So I have two classes, each consists of database integration tests. In each classes' constructor I put a method to reset the database:

```
public class FirstClassSpec {
    public FirstClassSpec() {
        var dataSetup = new DataSetup();
        dataSetup.CleanTables();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task FirstTest() {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection("connStringHere")){
            var result = await conn.ExecuteAsync("someSqlCommand");
            Assert.True(result > 0);
        }
    }
}

public class SecondClassSpec {
    public SecondClassSpec() {
        var dataSetup = new DataSetup();
        dataSetup.CleanTables();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SecondTest() {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection("connStringHere")){
            var result = await conn.ExecuteAsync("someSqlCommand");
            Assert.True(result > 0);
        }
    }
}

public class DataSetup {
    public void CleanTables() {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection("connStringHere")){
            await conn.Execute("someSqlCommandToCleanTables");
        }
    }
}
```

In order to run the tests Visual Studio 2015, I use `Run All Tests` in `Test Explorer`. I got the message of

> Transaction (Process ID {someID}) was deadlocked on lock resources
>   with another process

This problem only happens if I run all of the tests. If I run each tests one by one or running many tests but from the same class, the deadlock never occurs.
I found out that the `CleanTables()` method which is called in the classes' constructor cause this. I assume the tests run in parallel, and `CleanTables()` was called on the same time by the two classes.
So then I tried to make `CleanTables()` into an async method:

```
public async Task<int> CleanTables() {
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection("connStringHere")){
        return await conn.Execute("someSqlCommandToCleanTables");
    }
}
```

And then on the classes' constructor I call it like this:

```
public FirstClassSpec() {
    var dataSetup = new DataSetup();
    dataSetup.CleanTables().Wait();
}

public SecondClassSpec() {
    var dataSetup = new DataSetup();
    dataSetup.CleanTables().Wait();
}
```

But now when I try to `Run All Tests`, the tests were running but they never get done and I never get the result.

My question is, why the deadlock occurs? and why changing the `CleanTables()` method into async made the running tests never get done? I really need to clean the tables before each tests run.

**----------------- UPDATE -----------------------**

I've tried decorated all of the test classes with `[Collection["CollectionName"]]`, with each classes has different name:

```
[Collection["FirstSpec"]]
public class FirstClassSpec {
    //....
}

[Collection["SecondSpec"]]
public class FirstClassSpec {
    //....
}
```

But the deadlock still occurs..

**----------------- UPDATE 2 -----------------------**

Turns out classes which have the same collection name would be executed sequentially and this solves the deadlock problem.

Comment: Have you tried using [Sql Server Profiler to the analyze the deadlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/analyze-deadlocks-with-sql-server-profiler)? It has helped me in the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your guess is correct about the test running in parallel. By default xUnit will not run tests in the same class in parallel. So to fix your problem you could move all your tests into one class. Alternately you could decorate your classes with `[Collection("My Collection")]` to indicate that the tests in both classes should not be run in parallel.

You can find out more about how xUnit decides how to run tests in parallel here: https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html

Comment: Thanks for your solutions! But no I don't want to move all my tests into one class (it will become hard to maintain). I will try decorating my class with `[Collection["My Collection"]]` later today. If that's work I'll mark your answer as the answer! :)

Comment: I've tried decorated all of the test classes with [Collection["CollectionName"]], with each classes has different name.. But the deadlock still occurs.. I've updated my question..

Comment: Each class should have the same collection name.

Comment: It works! and now it makes sense to me, like because the classes' collectionName are the same, they were executed sequentially.. Thanks for your time man!

Comment: Wow, I did not think this would work after messing around with ConfigureAwait for days, but i tried it anyway out of desperation... et voila! Give this man a Bells! :-)